# How to read the code on a partial NOT gate

Tags: qiskit

In the code I am analyzing, I found the following code being:

```
frac = 1/(num+1)
qc.u(frac*math.pi,0,0,q[position])
```

Where I can insert any number integer to the variable num. I am not sure what the following code after the not gate represents with the 4 variables that it also needs to take. How does this also look in matrix format for example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Qiskit docs reference for `qc.u` https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.UGate